# How to check beginning of a string contains a number?

Tags: java, string, numbers

How to check the beginning of a string contains a number in Java and convert the same into a number?

```
String s="-495asadad";
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: You can use regex `(-?\d+)(.+)`

Comment: Similar but not the same: [How to check a string starts with numeric number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107798/how-to-check-a-string-starts-with-numeric-number) That question is about the string starting with a numeric character. This one is about starting with a (possibly) signed number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here and when you post a question, tell us what your search brought up and specify how it fell short of solving your problem. It’s for your own sake since (1) you often find a better answer faster that way (2) it allows us to give preciser and more focused answers. It also tends to prevent or at least reduce the number of downvotes.

Comment: Although the question lacks research, it is clear and therefore I disagree with the Closing reason and have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String s="-495asadad";

    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    Number num = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(s, pp);
    if (pp.getIndex() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No number there");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number found: " + num);
    }
```

Output:

> Number found: -495

You will probably want to consider more precisely what constitutes a number and from that, how your `NumberFormat` should work.

The two-arg `parse` method tries to parse a number from the specified position. In this case position 0, the start of the string. If successful, it will update the position to after the number. If not, it will remain 0, so this is what I test in the `if` statement.

Comment: Awesome! This is simply brilliant. I used to think that `ParsePosition` has application only with `DateTimeFormatter` and `SimpleDateFormat`.